# AR core / Is it possible to load two different 2D textures at the same time?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, arcore, texture-mapping

I'm making an AR makeup app application with google AR Core.

In the application, 2D lipstick texture and eye shadow texture are separate textures,
so you cannot apply lipstick and eye shadow textures at the same time.

So, is there any way that I can build two different textures at the same time?

Is it possible to load two different 2D textures at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would require that each of your texture images have an alpha for transparancy be placed at least 2 pixels apart, but the really hard part would be creating the shader code to display them...